# Gmail email styling, wrapper div not displaying

Tags: html, css, email, styles, gmail

I'm trying to style an email for gmail. Most of it displays just fine but Gmail is refusing to display the wrapper div apparently. I had a very similar wrapper working before so I can't figure out where the problem is coming from:

```
<div style=\"border: 1px solid black; width: 595px; height: 842px; background-color: white; border-radius: 10px; text-align: center; padding-top: 6px;\">AAA</div>
```

(The \" quotes are for PHP)

Gmail seems to remove the wrapper completely and display and div with no style.

Comment: Make sure your HTML is 100% valid, and everything is closed correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best practice to use tables for html-email. Divs and css when applied to divs have inconsistent support across email clients, particularly Gmail, which is probably what is causing issues for you.

Your html code should instead look like this:

```
<table width="595" height="842" align="right" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding-top: 6px;">
  <tr>
    <td>
      AAA
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that in many places I've used the old html methods instead of css. This is the best method for html-email.

Comment: Thank you, using a table indeed works much better. I'm only having one problem. My text is positioned in the center of the cell. I would like it at the top. Setting valign="top" in the tag or vertical-align:top; in the style doesn't have an effect (at least in gmail). How can I get the text to display at the top of the cell?

Comment: Use `valign="top"` in the `<td>` tag that contains the text.